# Convert char to string doesn't work fine C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, sfml

Well I have that code:

```
for (int x = 0; x<(worldWidth-1); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y<(worldHeight-1); y++) {
        sf::Texture texture;
        if (!texture.loadFromFile("images/blocks/" + ruta(mapa[y][x]) + ".png"))
        return -1;

        sf::RectangleShape rectCaja(sf::Vector2f(16, 16));
        rectCaja.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(x*16, y*16));
        rectCaja.setTexture(&texture);
        window.draw(rectCaja);
    }
}
```

That prints boxes (of 16*16 pixels), that are "blocks" in a game the problem is that it doesn't print any block, it crashes directly I don't know why :/

I know (by consoles tests) that array "mapa" isn't wrong... So the only explanation that I have is that ruta function doesn't work fine... (I have tested it with a std::string var = "dirt"; and it works fine)... :/

```
std::string ruta(char id) {

if (id=='0') return "air";
if (id=='1') return "stone";
if (id=='2') return "dirt";
if (id=='3') return "grass_side";
if (id=='4') return "coal_ore";

}
```

If somebody wants the hold code there is: http://pastebin.com/5jvbzwkR

Thanks! :P

Comment: You're comparing int id to a char

Comment: What if `id` is none of those things? (Did you get any compiler warnings?)

Comment: This code is going to be inefficient because every time you call ruta() it creates a new string to return. You would be better off creating an array, `const std::string ruta[] = { "air", "stone", "dirt", "grass_side", "coal_ore" };` and using ruta[mapa[y][x]].

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: How to convert a char array to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960087/c-how-to-convert-a-char-array-to-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a guess because there isn't enough information to be sure but this might be the answer

```
std::string ruta(int id) {

if (id==0) return "air";
if (id==1) return "stone";
if (id==2) return "dirt";
if (id==3) return "grass_side";
if (id==4) return "coal_ore";

}
```

In C++ you have to be careful about *types*, and understand the difference, for instance, between  an `int` and a `char`. A char with value '3' is not the same an an int with value 3.

Comment: Well I forget to change 'int' to 'char' in the function arguments but it is still crashing, I don't know why... :/

Comment: This is wrong `if (!texture.loadFromFile("images/blocks/" + ruta(mapa[y][x]) + ".png"))` should be `if (!texture.loadFromFile("images/blocks/" + ruta(mapa[x][y]) + ".png"))`. You got x and y the wrong way round.

Comment: This `char mapa[worldWidth-1][worldHeight-1];` looks wrong. Why not the obvious `char mapa[worldWidth][worldHeight];`? You might have a good reason for this, but I suspect it's just a mistake.

Comment: @Ikillnukes No I didn't say the same code, **you got x and y the wrong way round**.

Comment: @Ikillnukes You probably have lots of bugs in your code. You should use a debugger.

Comment: Wooooow!!! I'm so stupid!!! Thanks!! You should look at my codes, because I'm a little vague and blind xD

Answer (score 1):

One issue I immediately see is that you're comparing an `int` to a `char`. Consider:

```
std::string ruta(int id)
{
    switch( id )
    {
    case 0:
        return "air";
    case 1:
        return "stone";
    case 2:
        return "dirt";
    case 3:
        return "grass_side";
    case 4:
        return "coal_ore";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! I forget to put char id, but it is still crashing... :/

Answer (score 1):

Here is your scene declaration:

```
int scene[worldWidth][worldHeight];
```

Here is how you fill up your scene:

```
while (!finished) {
    if (yPos >= topOfTheWorld) {
        scene[xPos][yPos] = 1;
    } 
    else if(yPos < topOfTheWorld) {
        scene[xPos][yPos] = 0;
    }

    //etc...
}
```

Here is how you write into your mapa.txt:

```
std::ofstream output("mapa.txt");
for(int y=0;y<worldHeight;y++) {
    for(int x=0;x<worldWidth;x++) {
        output<<scene[x][y];

        if(x<(worldWidth-1)){output<<",";}
    }
    if(y<(worldHeight-1)){output<<std::endl;}
}
```

Basically this all means that you are writing the numerical value 0 and 1 into your mapa.txt and not the character values '0' and '1'. Yet in your ruta function you compare with '0' and '1'. You should compare with 0 and 1 without the single quotes (').

Comment: I'm writing that as you say, but when I charge all the map, it charge as a char and not as a int, so... I have to compare it as a char, not as a int... But if I do that, the application is still crashing... :/