# convert char to string

Tags: c++, string, char

Hello? I want to know "how to convert char to string"

This is my C code

```
    string firSen;
    int comma1=0;
    cout<<"Please write your sentence"<<endl;
    getline(cin,first);
    int a=firSen.first("string");

    for(i=a;firSen[i] != ',';i++)
        comma1=i;
    cout<<firSen[comma1-3]<<firSen[comma1-2]<<firSen[comma1-1]<<endl;
```

I will write "The string is 100s, Thank you"

I know firSen[comma1-3]=1, firSen[comma1-2]=0, firSen[comma1-1]=0 for type of char.

And I want to put these char into string
(Like 1,0,0 into string of 100) because I want to use atoi function....

Do you know how to convert char into string?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960087/how-to-convert-a-char-array-to-a-string

Comment: Doesn't the **char+""** do the trick?

Comment: Perhaps you should look up `std::stoi`.

Comment: Voted to close. (unclear what you are asking).

Comment: @Nabin, no. That will be equivalent to `""[c]` which is undefined behaviour unless `c==0`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::istringstream` instead of `atoi`.
Something like this:

`std::istringstream ss(firSen.substr(comma1-3));
int val;
ss >> val;`

Comment: Or just use `std::stoi` and the like.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, if you know the location and length that you want, you can just extract a substring:

```
std::string number(firSen, comma1-3, 3);
```

and convert that to an integer type using the C++11 conversion functions:

```
int n = std::stoi(number);
```

or, historically, a string stream:

```
int n;
std::stringstream ss(number);
ss >> n;
```

or, if you want to be really old-school, the C library

```
int n = std::atoi(number.c_str());
```

There are other ways of building strings. You can initialise it from a list of characters:

```
std::string number {char1, char2, char3};
```

You can append characters and other strings:

```
std::string hello = "Hello";
hello += ',';
hello += ' ';
hello += "world!";
```

or use a string stream, which can also format numbers and other types:

```
std::stringstream sentence;
sentence << "The string is " << 100 << ", thank you.";
```